# Extension of a rational map upto a compactification

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U$ be a smooth variety of dimension at most $2$ over a field $k$. Suppose $f: U \to X$ is a morphism of $k$-schemes where  $X$ is a smooth proper $k$-scheme. Then there is a smooth proper compactification $\bar{U}$ of $U$ such that $f$ can be extended to a morphism from $\bar{U}$ to X. 
I know this is true for curve. I can't find any proof in case of surface. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The morphism $f$ (or rather the pair $(U,f)$) represents a rational map out of *any* compactification of $U$. Now applying the theorem on resolution of indeterminacy for rational maps (and noting that the locus of indeterminacy is located in the boundary of the compactification so that after blowing up we still have a compactification of $U$) we get a compactification on which $f$ extends to a morphism. Finally, if the compactification is singular anywhere along the boundary, apply resolution of singularities.